# Apollo return error doing a query with subtype

Tags: node.js, neo4j, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I'm trying to create a query to login a user, the type of my query is the AuthPayload, inside this payload I have the token and the user:

```
type AuthPayload {
  token: String
  user: User
}
type User {
  uuid: ID!
  email: String
  password: String
}
```

this is the query I defined on my server:

```
login(email: String!, password: String!): AuthPayload @cypher( 
    statement: """
      MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.email = email AND u.password = password RETURN u
    """
 )
```

this is my resolver:

```
Query: {
    login: (parent, args, context, info) => svcUsers.login(parent, args, context, info),
}
```

this is my service:

```
login(parent, args, context, info){
    let user = null;
    const query = cypherQuery(args, context, info);
    return {
      token: '123',
      user: {
        email: '123',
        password: '321'
      }
    };
 }
```

and this is the query I'm trying to request:

```
query login($email: String!, $password: String!) {
  login(email: $email, password: $password) {
    token,
    user {
      email
    }
  }
}
```

the problem is that I get this error as resopnse: Cannot read property '0' of undefined but if I remove the user from the request:

```
query login($email: String!, $password: String!) {
  login(email: $email, password: $password) {
    token
  }
}
```

I can see a correct result with my token....where is the mistake?

many thanks